# AngularJS: Serving $resource via https, Angular switches from https to http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, nginx, https

I have set up a ng-resource in my AngularJS project which gets data from a REST API. Everything works fine in the development and testing environments (both run over http). However, in production the REST requests fails due to a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` error.

The whole page is served via https, therefore I would expect the Angular's request would also leave over https. I set up the resource with a relative path (e.g. /api/), however AngularJS seems to change from https to http.

**My questions**

1. What could cause the request to http instead of https even with the relative api urls?
2. Is there any good Angular documentation how to handle https requests for `$http` or `resource`?
3. Could this be a server config issue with nginx? To me it seems Angular is simply automatically switching from https to http.

**Full Error Message**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/api/data/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**AngularJS resource setup**

```
  .factory('Data', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
      return $resource('/api/data\\/', {}, {
          query: {
            url:'/api/data/',
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true}
      },
      { stripTrailingSlashes: false });
    }])
```

I have whitelisted http and https domains in the AngularJS project, but that didn't make any changes to the https requests.

```
.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    'self',
    'http://www.example.com/**',
    'https://www.example.com/**'
  ]);
})
```

Comment: I found the cause of the prob: stripTrailingSlashes: false only works from 1.3+ and I am running 1.2.X and I had a typo in the url. The url above is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not related with https, you can use Https with $http and $resource without any change. If only you access index with https, all request will be https.

The problem should be about "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header". You should enable CORS on your server side. There are already many guides about this.

Answer (score 0):

$sceDelegateProvider doesn't works with https. Only http is supported.